# Enthought Mayavi2 running errors on command line and through Mayavi

Tags: python, 3d, ipython, mayavi

If I run code from Python, the Mayavi2 plot window will either disappear really quick or if it doesn't, I can't interact with it because it freezes.

However, if I run `mayavi2 /path/to/code`, I can interact with the figure without any issue.

Additionally, if I run Mayavi2 normally, I receive in the logger the following error:

> could not restore editor [TVTK Scene 1]

Then when I close Mayavi2 I receive this error:

> (python:1820): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

If I run it as `sudo`, I receive

> (python:5288): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/dustin/.config/ibus/bus is not root!

What is the deal with this program? How can I fix any of these issues?

Comment: Try running IPython with `--pylab` - it has some tricks to allow interactive windows while it's running.

Comment: @ThomasK that doesn't stop it from happening either.   I also tried `ipython --pylab=qt`

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8 (and feel free to file a new bug if you think it's warranted).

Comment: maybe it is due the backend you chose from Mayavi's preferences (Tools > Preferences > Mayavi > mlab > backend). I use the default option auto and it works fine with ```$ ipython --gui=wx```